# Understanding key's and values of a hashtable

Tags: powershell, csv, key, hashtable

I'm currently reading through a book and I came across an example regarding hash tables, we have a CSV file that we would like to pipe to `New-ADUser`, the CSV looks like this:

[image]

The property names do not match those that are accepted by `New-ADUser` therefore `Import-CSV .\newusers.csv | New-ADUser` will not work, but we can create a hash table to change the property name's to match the input that is accepted by `New-ADUser`, the solution provided by the book is this:

```
C:\> import-csv .\newusers.csv |
>> select-object -property *,
>> @{name='samAccountName';expression={$_.login}},
>> @{label='Name';expression={$_.login}},
>> @{n='Department';e={$_.Dept}}
```

I understand that there is a key and a value associated with it, there are 3 key's in total, my questions about this particular solution are:

- Why does the Key have to be Name, N, Label, or L? Can I not put in a custom key name? What is the significance of using Name, N, Label, or L ?
- The Value for the key's `samAccountName` and `Name` are both `$_.Login` ... Where does `$_.Login` come from? What does it mean in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Key represents the property name of your property which you have to define using the mentioned `name` or `label` identifier. The name of the property will be the value you assigned to the key.

The `$_.Login` comes from your CSV. You have to append `$_.` because you are accessing the property in an expression.

Comment: That clears things up, but I still don't get why I have to use `Name` or `Label` to specify the property name? Couldn't I use `custom01` and `custom02` instead, I would still have the same property name and value regardless? The property name would still be able to pass through `New-ADUser` `ByPropertyName` so I don't see how not using `name` and `label` could change that?

Comment: How would PowerShell know that `custom01` is the name of the property? You have to specify the property name e. g. `custom01` using an identifier which is `name` or `label`

Comment: Sorry my wording has been poor, my question here is: does the identifier have to be `name` or `label`? for example: 

`@{name='samAccountName';expression={$_.login}}` 
and
`@{custom='samAccountName';expression={$_.login}}` 

Specify a property name of `samAccountName` and value of `$_.login`, but the identifier has been changed, does the identifier that is used change anything? If not, is there a difference between the name or label identifier, or is the identifier just used to keep things organized?

Comment: Yes, the identifier have to be name or label but its only used that powershell what the actual identifier is. So name = samAccountName makes a new property called samAccountName with the value you specifiy in the expression. There is no difference between name or label.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for, I appreciate your help

Comment: The feature is called [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Awesome, that link really helped!